# How to use regex to get file extension?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying extract a substring from a string that contains a filename or directory. The substring being extracted should be the file extension. I've done some searching online and discovered I can use regular expressions to accomplish this. I've found that `^\.[\w]+$` is a pattern that will work to find file extensions. The problem is that I'm not fully familiar with regular expressions and its functions.

Basically If i have a string like `C:\Desktop\myFile.txt` I want the regular expression to then find and create a new string containing only `.txt`

Comment: For you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ (A great resource that has many language-independent and language-specific aids.)

Comment: OP just wants to extract extension which is not what has been asked in dupe question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use String class split() function. Here you could pass a regular expression. In this case, it would be "\.". This will split the string in two parts the second part will give you the file extension.

```
public class Sample{
  public static void main(String arg[]){
    String filename= "c:\\abc.txt";

    String fileArray[]=filename.split("\\.");

    System.out.println(fileArray[fileArray.length-1]); //Will print the file extension
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Regex to capture file extension is:

```
(\\.[^.]+)$
```

Note that dot needs to be escaped to match a literal dot. However `[^.]` is a character class with negation that doesn't require any escaping since `dot` is treated literally inside `[` and `]`.

```
\\.        # match a literal dot
[^.]+      # match 1 or more of any character but dot
(\\.[^.]+) # capture above test in group #1
$          # anchor to match end of input
```

Comment: I don't think a space can be part of a file extension? Perhaps `[\w]` or `[^\s]`  instead of `[^.]`?

Comment: @Inigo: A unix file system allows any character to be used as extension.  I can create a file with the name `a.b c` as well

Comment: Sure, but I really doubt that would count as a file extension, just a file with a dot in its name. My 2¢.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use RegEx you can go with something like this:

```
String fileString = "..." //this is your String representing the File
int lastDot = fileString.lastIndexOf('.');
String extension = fileString.subString(lastDot+1);
```